# JSP trimDirectiveWhitespaces

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am testing several ways to improve and reduce my response size, network traffic, and load time.
One of the things I thought of using is the trimDirectiveWhitespaces element.
 I placed it in the page directive:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

I added  some empty new lines and didn't see any change in my response or when i view source of the document, new lines were there.

What is the correct usage of this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should see the source html which has been generated. trimDirectiveWhitespaces will change the source html and not the response that you see on Internet browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i checked both the source using view source   is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I hope I have been able to resolve your query. I have also posted a small info , so that it can help you further

Comment: thanks, but the source still displays the newlines, thanks for the nelow answer, see my question there

Comment: DOes it help putting page encoding ??  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" 
trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>

Comment: Nope, I also tried your suggestion below just in-case which didn't help either, can there be other configurations overwriting mine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61362/discussion-between-samdjava-and-ninana).

Answer (score 15):

*trimDirectiveWhitespaces* only removes empty lines around JSP tags and leaves other empty lines as they are.

Example:

```html
<% page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>X
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>X
<html>


<head>
```

This will become:

```
X
X
<html>


<head>
```

(note I added `X` to mark end-of-line for this example, so it is more obvious and stackoverflow wont trim them out)

If `trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"` is added to the `page` directive, the output becomes:

```
<html>


<head>
```

The first two empty lines are removed, but the next two (between the `html` and `head` tags) are preserved.

Comment: This explain how trimDirectiveWhitespaces work. But, the question is how to remove white spaces inner elements to improve speed response between server pages.

Comment: @GiovanCruz Well, the question was "What is the correct usage of this (the trimDirectiveWhitespaces directive) ?" For removing other white space, a new question should be opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the following configuration for `trim-directive-whitespaces` in `web.xml` as well:

```
<web-app xmlns=...>
(...)
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
(...)
</web-app>
```

Comment: in my specific application it make smore sense to put it directly in the jsp, will it behave differently, will it explain why it's not working if i use the web.xml approach?

Comment: No, It will just be more generic. If you put it in the page then it applies only to the particular webpage.